# An optimization in this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, autocomplete, information-retrieval

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete feature for a search engine. I have a database of words(stemmed) that occur in the documents that I have. what I'm doing is:

- Constructing a graph with words as nodes and weighted edges with weights as the number of times those 2 words have been searched together.
- Each node also keeps track of which is the most commonly typed word next to it.
- Whenever a user starts typing his query, this graph is queried and the first word is predicted by string matching and then ranking the matched words according to search frequency.
- When the user starts typing the next word, the graph is visited and the neighbours of this node are retrieved and shown to the user in order of frequency(weight of edges.).

This is a rough overview of what I am trying to achieve. Are there any optimizations that could be made to this or something else entirely that can replace this?

Comment: This is too broad of a question. I'm certain that there are in fact optimizations or other options for doing what you are trying to do, but there is no way to have a single definitive answer to your question. I'm going to flag it as such, but I would encourage you to refine this question down to be more specific, so that it can get legitimate answers

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel... What you would want is a language model that given a current context, would predict the next word, i.e. given (w_1,...w_{n-1}) choose w_n such that P(w_n|w_1,...w_{n-1}) is maximized... use the SRILM toolkit or neural language models such as Mikolov's word2vec.